# Can't scan the transponders from a satellite using w_scan

Tags: dvb, linux-tv

I'm trying to use `w_scan` to scan the transponders from a satellite, on Debian 8.0 it worked, but on Debian 8.7 it doesn't work.

At the same time, i can scan all the transponders by using Kaffeine (Version 1.2.2).

I.e. all is almost good, but I really need to get `w_scan` to work as well.

How to solve the problem?

```
sudo w_scan -t2 -l 10750,10750,0 -o21 -fs -sS36E0 -v -v
```

**Log:**

```
w_scan version 20161022 (compiled for DVB API 5.10)
using settings for 36.0 east Eutelsat 36A/36B
scan type SATELLITE, channellist 58
output format vdr-2.1
WARNING: could not guess your codepage. Falling back to 'UTF-8'
output charset 'UTF-8', use -C  to override
Info: using DVB adapter auto detection.
   check Conexant CX24116/CX24118:
           DVB-S2
           DVB-S
        /dev/dvb/adapter0/frontend0 -> SATELLITE "Conexant CX24116/CX24118": very good :-))

Using SATELLITE frontend (adapter /dev/dvb/adapter0/frontend0)
-_-_-_-_ Getting frontend capabilities-_-_-_-_ 
Using DVB API 5.10
frontend 'Conexant CX24116/CX24118' supports
INVERSION_AUTO
DVB-S
DVB-S2
FREQ (0.95GHz ... 2.15GHz)
SRATE (1.000MSym/s ... 45.000MSym/s)
using LNB "(null)"
-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_ 
   check Conexant CX24116/CX24118:
           DVB-S2
           DVB-S
trying 'S  f = 11109 kHz V SR =  3418  2/3 0,35  QPSK  (0:0:0)'
(time: 00:00.331)        skipped: (freq 0.36 unsupported by driver: min=0.95, max=2.15)

initial_tune:2722: Setting frontend failed S  f = 11109 kHz V SR =  3418  2/3 0,35  QPSK  (0:0:0)
trying 'S  f = 11439 kHz H SR =  8250  5/6 0,35  QPSK  (0:0:0)'
(time: 00:00.331)        skipped: (freq 0.69 unsupported by driver: min=0.95, max=2.15)

initial_tune:2722: Setting frontend failed S  f = 11439 kHz H SR =  8250  5/6 0,35  QPSK  (0:0:0)
trying 'S  f = 11644 kHz V SR =  2170  3/4 0,35  QPSK  (0:0:0)'
(time: 00:00.331)        skipped: (freq 0.89 unsupported by driver: min=0.95, max=2.15)

initial_tune:2722: Setting frontend failed S  f = 11644 kHz V SR =  2170  3/4 0,35  QPSK  (0:0:0)
trying 'S  f = 11648 kHz V SR =  3110  3/4 0,35  QPSK  (0:0:0)'
(time: 00:00.331)        skipped: (freq 0.90 unsupported by driver: min=0.95, max=2.15)

initial_tune:2722: Setting frontend failed S  f = 11648 kHz V SR =  3110  3/4 0,35  QPSK  (0:0:0)
trying 'S  f = 11652 kHz V SR =  3110  3/4 0,35  QPSK  (0:0:0)'
(time: 00:00.331)        skipped: (freq 0.90 unsupported by driver: min=0.95, max=2.15)

initial_tune:2722: Setting frontend failed S  f = 11652 kHz V SR =  3110  3/4 0,35  QPSK  (0:0:0)
trying 'S2 f = 11692 kHz V SR =  1555  5/6 0,AUTO  8PSK  (0:0:0)'
(time: 00:00.331)        skipped: (freq 0.94 unsupported by driver: min=0.95, max=2.15)

initial_tune:2722: Setting frontend failed S2 f = 11692 kHz V SR =  1555  5/6 0,AUTO  8PSK  (0:0:0)
trying 'S  f = 11727 kHz V SR = 27500  3/4 0,35  QPSK  (0:0:0)'
(time: 00:00.331) 
        (0.864sec): SC (0x3)
        (0.864sec) signal
        (0.916sec): S (0x1)
        (1.068sec): SC (0x3)
        (1.272sec): S (0x1)
        (1.320sec): SC (0x3)
        (1.472sec): S (0x1)
        (1.524sec): SC (0x3)
        (1.576sec): S (0x1)
        (1.676sec): SC (0x3)
        (1.728sec): S (0x1)
        (1.828sec): SC (0x3)
        (1.880sec): S (0x1)
        (1.928sec): SC (0x3)
        (1.980sec): S (0x1)
        (2.084sec): SC (0x3)
        (2.132sec): S (0x1)
        (2.284sec): SC (0x3)
        (2.436sec): S (0x1)
        (2.488sec): SC (0x3)
trying 'S  f = 11747 kHz H SR = 27500  3/4 0,35  QPSK  (0:0:0)'
(time: 00:02.971) 
        (0.868sec): S (0x1)
        (0.868sec) signal
        (0.920sec): SC (0x3)
        (0.968sec): S (0x1)
        (1.324sec): SC (0x3)
        (1.376sec): S (0x1)
        (1.628sec): SC (0x3)
        (1.680sec): S (0x1)
        (1.732sec): SC (0x3)
        (1.984sec): S (0x1)
        (2.136sec): SC (0x3)
        (2.240sec): S (0x1)
        (2.492sec): SC (0x3)
        (2.544sec): S (0x1)
trying 'S  f = 11766 kHz V SR = 27500  3/4 0,35  QPSK  (0:0:0)'
(time: 00:05.615) 
        (0.864sec): SC (0x3)
        (0.864sec) signal
        (0.964sec): S (0x1)
        (1.168sec): SC (0x3)
        (1.220sec): S (0x1)
        (1.776sec): SC (0x3)
        (1.880sec): S (0x1)
        (2.032sec): SC (0x3)
        (2.132sec): S (0x1)
        (2.184sec): SC (0x3)
        (2.236sec): S (0x1)
        (2.436sec): SC (0x3)
        (2.488sec): S (0x1)
        (2.592sec): SC (0x3)
        (2.640sec): S (0x1)
trying 'S  f = 11785 kHz H SR = 27500  3/4 0,35  QPSK  (0:0:0)'
(time: 00:08.255) 
        (0.864sec): S (0x1)
        (0.864sec) signal
        (0.916sec): SC (0x3)
        (0.964sec): S (0x1)
        (1.016sec): SC (0x3)
        (1.116sec): S (0x1)
        (1.168sec): SC (0x3)
        (1.220sec): S (0x1)
        (1.272sec): SC (0x3)
        (1.372sec): S (0x1)
        (1.472sec): SC (0x3)
        (1.624sec): S (0x1)
        (1.676sec): SC (0x3)
        (1.776sec): S (0x1)
        (2.388sec): SC (0x3)
        (2.436sec): S (0x1)
        (2.540sec): SC (0x3)
trying 'S  f = 11823 kHz H SR = 27500  3/4 0,35  QPSK  (0:0:0)'
(time: 00:10.895) 
        (0.864sec): S (0x1)
        (0.864sec) signal
        (1.168sec): SC (0x3)
        (1.220sec): S (0x1)
        (1.272sec): SC (0x3)
        (1.320sec): S (0x1)
        (1.472sec): SC (0x3)
        (1.524sec): S (0x1)
        (1.676sec): SC (0x3)
        (1.728sec): S (0x1)
        (1.880sec): SC (0x3)
        (1.932sec): S (0x1)
        (2.388sec): SC (0x3)
        (2.436sec): S (0x1)
        (2.488sec): SC (0x3)
        (2.588sec): S (0x1)
trying 'S  f = 11843 kHz V SR = 27500  3/4 0,35  QPSK  (0:0:0)'
(time: 00:13.535) 
        (0.864sec): S (0x1)
        (0.864sec) signal
        (1.016sec): SC (0x3)
        (1.116sec): S (0x1)
        (1.624sec): SC (0x3)
        (1.676sec): S (0x1)
        (1.728sec): SC (0x3)
        (1.828sec): S (0x1)
        (1.928sec): SC (0x3)
        (2.032sec): S (0x1)
        (2.084sec): SC (0x3)
        (2.184sec): S (0x1)
        (2.284sec): SC (0x3)
        (2.336sec): S (0x1)
        (2.540sec): SC (0x3)
        (2.640sec): S (0x1)
trying 'S  f = 11862 kHz H SR = 27500  3/4 0,35  QPSK  (0:0:0)'
(time: 00:16.175) 
        (0.852sec): S (0x1)
        (0.852sec) signal
        (1.052sec): SC (0x3)
        (1.104sec): S (0x1)
        (1.204sec): SC (0x3)
        (1.256sec): S (0x1)
        (1.460sec): SC (0x3)
        (1.512sec): S (0x1)
        (1.712sec): SC (0x3)
        (1.816sec): S (0x1)
        (1.864sec): SC (0x3)
        (1.916sec): S (0x1)
        (2.220sec): SC (0x3)
        (2.272sec): S (0x1)
        (2.524sec): SC (0x3)
        (2.576sec): S (0x1)
trying 'S  f = 11881 kHz V SR = 27500  3/4 0,35  QPSK  (0:0:0)'
(time: 00:18.802) 
        (0.848sec): S (0x1)
        (0.848sec) signal
        (1.560sec): SC (0x3)
        (1.712sec): S (0x1)
        (1.760sec): SC (0x3)
        (1.864sec): S (0x1)
        (1.964sec): SC (0x3)
        (2.016sec): S (0x1)
        (2.068sec): SC (0x3)
        (2.116sec): S (0x1)
        (2.220sec): SC (0x3)
        (2.372sec): S (0x1)
        (2.420sec): SC (0x3)
        (2.576sec): S (0x1)
trying 'S  f = 11900 kHz H SR = 27500  3/4 0,35  QPSK  (0:0:0)'
(time: 00:21.426) 
        (0.848sec): S (0x1)
        (0.848sec) signal
        (1.356sec): SC (0x3)
        (1.408sec): S (0x1)
        (1.456sec): SC (0x3)
        (1.508sec): S (0x1)
        (1.660sec): SC (0x3)
        (1.812sec): S (0x1)
        (2.016sec): SC (0x3)
        (2.116sec): S (0x1)
        (2.320sec): SC (0x3)
        (2.372sec): S (0x1)
        (2.420sec): SC (0x3)
        (2.472sec): S (0x1)
        (2.524sec): SC (0x3)
        (2.576sec): S (0x1)
trying 'S  f = 11919 kHz V SR = 27500  3/4 0,35  QPSK  (0:0:0)'
(time: 00:24.050) 
        (0.864sec): SC (0x3)
        (0.864sec) signal
        (0.916sec): S (0x1)
        (1.016sec): SC (0x3)
        (1.168sec): S (0x1)
        (1.220sec): SC (0x3)
        (1.272sec): S (0x1)
        (1.320sec): SC (0x3)
        (1.372sec): S (0x1)
        (1.424sec): SC (0x3)
        (1.472sec): S (0x1)
        (1.576sec): SC (0x3)
        (1.624sec): S (0x1)
        (1.728sec): SC (0x3)
        (1.776sec): S (0x1)
        (1.828sec): SC (0x3)
        (1.932sec): S (0x1)
        (2.084sec): SC (0x3)
        (2.136sec): S (0x1)
        (2.236sec): SC (0x3)
        (2.440sec): S (0x1)
        (2.488sec): SC (0x3)
trying 'S  f = 11940 kHz H SR = 27500  3/4 0,35  QPSK  (0:0:0)'
(time: 00:26.690) 
        (0.864sec): SC (0x3)
        (0.864sec) signal
        (0.916sec): S (0x1)
        (0.964sec): SC (0x3)
        (1.016sec): S (0x1)
        (1.424sec): SC (0x3)
        (1.472sec): S (0x1)
        (1.576sec): SC (0x3)
        (1.676sec): S (0x1)
        (1.828sec): SC (0x3)
        (1.932sec): S (0x1)
        (1.984sec): SC (0x3)
        (2.032sec): S (0x1)
        (2.132sec): SC (0x3)
        (2.284sec): S (0x1)
        (2.488sec): SC (0x3)
        (2.540sec): S (0x1)
trying 'S  f = 11958 kHz V SR = 27500  3/4 0,35  QPSK  (0:0:0)'
(time: 00:29.330) 
        (0.864sec): S (0x1)
        (0.864sec) signal
        (0.964sec): SC (0x3)
        (1.016sec): S (0x1)
        (1.068sec): SC (0x3)
        (1.120sec): S (0x1)
        (1.324sec): SC (0x3)
        (1.472sec): S (0x1)
        (1.628sec): SC (0x3)
        (1.676sec): S (0x1)
        (2.084sec): SC (0x3)
        (2.136sec): S (0x1)
        (2.184sec): SC (0x3)
        (2.284sec): S (0x1)
        (2.336sec): SC (0x3)
        (2.388sec): S (0x1)
        (2.488sec): SC (0x3)
        (2.540sec): S (0x1)
trying 'S  f = 11977 kHz H SR = 27500  3/4 0,35  QPSK  (0:0:0)'
(time: 00:31.970) 
        (0.864sec): S (0x1)
        (0.864sec) signal
        (1.168sec): SC (0x3)
        (1.220sec): S (0x1)
        (1.272sec): SC (0x3)
        (1.476sec): S (0x1)
        (1.624sec): SC (0x3)
        (1.676sec): S (0x1)
        (1.728sec): SC (0x3)
        (1.780sec): S (0x1)
        (1.828sec): SC (0x3)
        (1.880sec): S (0x1)
        (1.932sec): SC (0x3)
        (1.984sec): S (0x1)
        (2.032sec): SC (0x3)
        (2.084sec): S (0x1)
        (2.588sec): SC (0x3)
        (2.640sec): S (0x1)
trying 'S  f = 11996 kHz V SR = 27500  3/4 0,35  QPSK  (0:0:0)'
(time: 00:34.609) 
        (0.880sec): S (0x1)
        (0.880sec) signal
        (0.980sec): SC (0x3)
        (1.032sec): S (0x1)
        (1.288sec): SC (0x3)
        (1.440sec): S (0x1)
        (1.848sec): SC (0x3)
        (1.896sec): S (0x1)
        (2.000sec): SC (0x3)
        (2.148sec): S (0x1)
        (2.504sec): SC (0x3)
        (2.608sec): S (0x1)
        (2.656sec): SC (0x3)
trying 'S  f = 12015 kHz H SR = 27500  3/4 0,35  QPSK  (0:0:0)'
(time: 00:37.265) 
        (0.880sec): S (0x1)
        (0.880sec) signal
        (0.932sec): SC (0x3)
        (0.980sec): S (0x1)
        (1.084sec): SC (0x3)
        (1.184sec): S (0x1)
        (1.288sec): SC (0x3)
        (1.336sec): S (0x1)
        (1.388sec): SC (0x3)
        (1.540sec): S (0x1)
        (2.352sec): SC (0x3)
        (2.404sec): S (0x1)
        (2.452sec): SC (0x3)
        (2.556sec): S (0x1)
        (2.608sec): SC (0x3)
trying 'S  f = 12034 kHz V SR = 27500  3/4 0,35  QPSK  (0:0:0)'
(time: 00:39.925) 
        (0.876sec): S (0x1)
        (0.876sec) signal
        (0.928sec): SC (0x3)
        (0.980sec): S (0x1)
        (1.132sec): SC (0x3)
        (1.280sec): S (0x1)
        (1.336sec): SC (0x3)
        (1.384sec): S (0x1)
        (1.688sec): SC (0x3)
        (1.740sec): S (0x1)
        (2.044sec): SC (0x3)
        (2.096sec): S (0x1)
        (2.196sec): SC (0x3)
        (2.448sec): S (0x1)
        (2.500sec): SC (0x3)
        (2.600sec): S (0x1)
trying 'S  f = 12054 kHz H SR = 27500  3/4 0,35  QPSK  (0:0:0)'
(time: 00:42.577) 
        (0.852sec): S (0x1)
        (0.852sec) signal
        (0.904sec): SC (0x3)
        (1.004sec): S (0x1)
        (1.308sec): SC (0x3)
        (1.356sec): S (0x1)
        (1.564sec): SC (0x3)
        (1.612sec): S (0x1)
        (1.816sec): SC (0x3)
        (1.864sec): S (0x1)
        (1.968sec): SC (0x3)
        (2.020sec): S (0x1)
        (2.068sec): SC (0x3)
        (2.220sec): S (0x1)
        (2.428sec): SC (0x3)
        (2.476sec): S (0x1)
        (2.528sec): SC (0x3)
        (2.580sec): S (0x1)
trying 'S  f = 12073 kHz V SR = 27500  3/4 0,35  QPSK  (0:0:0)'
(time: 00:45.205) 
        (0.848sec): S (0x1)
        (0.848sec) signal
        (1.000sec): SC (0x3)
        (1.052sec): S (0x1)
        (1.360sec): SC (0x3)
        (1.460sec): S (0x1)
        (1.764sec): SC (0x3)
        (1.864sec): S (0x1)
        (1.916sec): SC (0x3)
        (2.016sec): S (0x1)
        (2.220sec): SC (0x3)
        (2.268sec): S (0x1)
        (2.524sec): SC (0x3)
        (2.628sec): S (0x1)
trying 'S  f = 12245 kHz H SR = 27500  3/4 0,35  QPSK  (0:0:0)'
(time: 00:47.833) 
        (0.876sec): S (0x1)
        (0.876sec) signal
        (1.080sec): SC (0x3)
        (1.184sec): S (0x1)
        (1.284sec): SC (0x3)
        (1.336sec): S (0x1)
        (1.844sec): SC (0x3)
        (1.892sec): S (0x1)
        (2.044sec): SC (0x3)
        (2.148sec): S (0x1)
        (2.452sec): SC (0x3)
        (2.500sec): S (0x1)
trying 'S2 f = 12284 kHz H SR = 27500  3/4 0,AUTO  QPSK  (0:0:0)'
(time: 00:50.488) 
        (0.100sec): SC (0x3)
        (0.100sec) signal
        (0.152sec): S (0x1)
        (0.404sec): SC (0x3)
        (0.604sec): S (0x1)
        (0.708sec): SC (0x3)
        (0.756sec): S (0x1)
        (0.908sec): SC (0x3)
        (0.964sec): S (0x1)
        (1.112sec): SC (0x3)
        (1.216sec): S (0x1)
        (1.268sec): SC (0x3)
        (1.320sec): S (0x1)
        (1.368sec): SC (0x3)
        (1.420sec): S (0x1)
        (1.472sec): SC (0x3)
        (1.520sec): S (0x1)
        (1.624sec): SC (0x3)
        (1.724sec): S (0x1)
        (1.824sec): SC (0x3)
        (1.876sec): S (0x1)
trying 'S  f = 12437 kHz H SR = 23438  3/4 0,35  QPSK  (0:0:0)'
(time: 00:52.364) 
        (0.848sec): S (0x1)
        (0.848sec) signal
        (0.952sec): SC (0x3)
        (1.004sec): S (0x1)
        (1.104sec): SC (0x3)
        (1.156sec): S (0x1)
        (1.204sec): SC (0x3)
        (1.256sec): S (0x1)
        (1.456sec): SC (0x3)
        (1.560sec): S (0x1)
        (1.712sec): SC (0x3)
        (1.868sec): S (0x1)
        (1.968sec): SC (0x3)
        (2.020sec): S (0x1)
        (2.068sec): SC (0x3)
        (2.120sec): S (0x1)
        (2.172sec): SC (0x3)
        (2.272sec): S (0x1)
        (2.476sec): SC (0x3)
        (2.576sec): S (0x1)
trying 'S  f = 12508 kHz H SR =  2278  5/6 0,35  QPSK  (0:0:0)'
(time: 00:54.992) 
        (0.848sec): S (0x1)
        (0.848sec) signal
        (1.612sec): SC (0x3)
        (1.812sec): S (0x1)
trying 'S  f = 12512 kHz H SR =  4340  1/2 0,35  QPSK  (0:0:0)'
(time: 00:57.616) 
        (0.836sec): S (0x1)
        (0.836sec) signal
trying 'S  f = 12521 kHz H SR =  4340  1/2 0,35  QPSK  (0:0:0)'
(time: 01:00.228) 
        (0.836sec): S (0x1)
        (0.836sec) signal
trying 'S  f = 12542 kHz V SR =  2220  3/4 0,35  QPSK  (0:0:0)'
(time: 01:02.840) 
        (0.836sec): S (0x1)
        (0.836sec) signal
trying 'S  f = 12573 kHz V SR =  2170  3/4 0,35  QPSK  (0:0:0)'
(time: 01:05.456) 
        (0.836sec): S (0x1)
        (0.836sec) signal
        (1.800sec): SC (0x3)
        (1.952sec): S (0x1)
trying 'S  f = 12620 kHz V SR =  2894  3/4 0,35  QPSK  (0:0:0)'
(time: 01:08.067) 
        (0.836sec): S (0x1)
        (0.836sec) signal
trying 'S  f = 12626 kHz V SR =  2890  3/4 0,35  QPSK  (0:0:0)'
(time: 01:10.679) 
        (0.836sec): S (0x1)
        (0.836sec) signal
trying 'S  f = 12630 kHz H SR =  2238  5/6 0,35  QPSK  (0:0:0)'
(time: 01:13.291) 
        (0.836sec): S (0x1)
        (0.836sec) signal
        (1.952sec): SC (0x3)
        (2.104sec): S (0x1)

ERROR: Sorry - i couldn't get any working frequency/transponder
 Nothing to scan!!
```

> 

#### A test with szap:

```
sudo szap  -H -r -c /var/lib/vdr/channels.conf -n 1 -x -l 10750,10750,0
reading channels from file '/var/lib/vdr/channels.conf'
zapping to 1 'KHL Channel;NTV+':
sat 0, frequency = 11785 MHz V, symbolrate 27500000, vpid = 0x0141, apid = 0x0191 sid = 0x0000
using '/dev/dvb/adapter0/frontend0' and '/dev/dvb/adapter0/demux0'
Version: 5.10    FE_CAN { DVB-S + DVB-S2 }
status 03 | signal  89% | snr   0% | ber 0 | unc 0 | 
status 03 | signal  89% | snr   0% | ber 0 | unc 0 | 
status 01 | signal  89% | snr   0% | ber 0 | unc 0 | 
status 01 | signal  89% | snr   0% | ber 0 | unc 0 | 
status 03 | signal  89% | snr   0% | ber 0 | unc 0 | 
status 03 | signal  89% | snr   0% | ber 0 | unc 0 | 
status 01 | signal  89% | snr   0% | ber 0 | unc 0 | 
status 03 | signal  89% | snr   0% | ber 0 | unc 0 | 
status 01 | signal  89% | snr   0% | ber 0 | unc 0 | 
status 01 | signal  89% | snr   0% | ber 0 | unc 0 |
```

Have not seen `FE_HAS_LOCK`

Comment: Please [edit] your question and give us something to go on. How are you using `w_scan`? What command? How is it failing? Any error messages? Any output? Wrong output? Is it crashing? We can't help unless you explain what the problem is.

Comment: i have updated the question.

Comment: As far as I remember the `w_scan`is not working when `Kaffeine` or other programs are running (maybe a `lsof /dev/dvb/adapter0/frontend0`or `lsof /dev/dvb/adapter0/demux0`or `lsof /dev/dvb/adapter0` might give more infos on what is interfering...)